# Doing something almost completely

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to reply to an email from a research collaborator. He sent me an article of his and asked me to review it. My question is what is the proper word/phrase to convey that I have read the article "almost completely" or "almost thoroughly". I have this in mind- 'I have **fairly** read your article'. But I need better suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: *Essentially?* *Effectively*? *Sufficiently*? Note that I'm only throwing out guess and not providing an actual answer. You need to be clearer in what you're looking for.

Comment: @JasonBassford Since the verb here is 'to read', I guess *sufficiently* would better fit in from the guesses you made. I'm looking for some word/phrase which describes that I've adequately done a job, although not completely (like 100%)

Comment: It seems from your question that you'd be happy with something longer than a single word; if that's the case you might want to edit your question to add _idiom-requests_ and _phrase-requests_ tags.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't belong here. If it did, you might at worst define a fair description and ask for a synonym - which would still not be appropriate. What you're actually asking belongs in a dictionary.

Since you're here, why would you want anything but "glanced at" or "skimmed over"?

Comment: Thanks tmgr and Robbie. I've added the phrase-request tag. @Robbie can you suggest me a reverse dictionary website where they give out word-suggestions for some description of what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry; I know nothing of reverse dictionaries.

Can we be clear, "almost completely" and "almost thoroughly" are not the same; not at all? 

If they were still, "I have fairly read…" would not be comparable nor, either way, comprehensible..

If you really see no difference, I think you're letting down your research collaborator.

Like anyone else, you're welcome to disagree and if you do, how will you justify that?

Comment: By the way, "can you suggest me…" will always be wrong.

"Can you suggest…" will work.

"Can you suggest *to* me…" will work.

Are those differences clear?

Comment: OK, I'm happy with 'skimmed over'. And those differences are clear to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on context, I would say something like "I skimmed over it", or "I did a first pass, and here's my feedback" (this assumes you intend to do at least another pass).

Or maybe just say directly: I did not read very carefully, but here's what I think: <...>

Answer (score 0):

How about wording it ‘I have read the majority of your article’? This conveys that you have read most, but not all, of it.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majority